# Advice on how to show that the following inequalities hold

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, asymptotics, maxima-minima

I am trying to show that the following inequalties hold 
$$\exp[\frac{k^2}{b^2 t}]  \log ^{\alpha_2 -1}(t) \left(\frac{1}{2} \log (t) -\alpha_2\right) \leq  \frac{k}{\sqrt{2 \pi b^2}} \leq  \exp[\frac{k^2}{b^2 t}] \log ^{-\alpha_1 -1}(t) \left(\alpha_1 + \frac{1}{2} \log (t)\right),$$

where $k$, $b$ are positive constants and $\alpha_1 > 1$ and $\alpha_2 > -4$ and $t$ is the time variable.

I am concerned if the inequalities will hold for all values of $t$, but it seems difficult to isolate $t$.

Obviously the standard approach will be to find the inflection points for both the lower and the upper bound and isolate the maximum and the minimum values, but that again requires isolating $t$ which seems really hard.

How can one prove such a problem.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thats an awesome idea thank you

Comment: For t>1 the right-most expression is positive, so you can divide both sides of the inequality by that expression without reversing the direction of the <.  After doing this you will end up with a fairly simple expression on the left and a 1 on the right.  It might be easy to show this simpl(er) inequality.